# What this line mean in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I came across to this line in one of the makefiles I examine. I am afraid that my guess might be completely wrong since I don't know what the double quotes are for in the assignment.

```
PROJECT_CONF_H=\"project-conf.h\"
```

What is the purpose of the double quotes In the assignment? Can't I just type

```
PROJECT_CONF_H=\project-conf.h\
```

?
I wasn't able to find the answer into the GNUmake manual so I decided to ask you for help. Please explain.
Sorry but the English is not my native language.

AFTER EDITION:

```
DEFINES += PROJECT_CONF_H=\"project-conf.h\"

CFLAGS += ${addprefix -D,${subst $(COMMA), ,$(DEFINES)}}
```

Where CFLAGS are the compiler option flags.
The option -D has the same effect as a #define statement at the top of the source file.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Variable assignment.

The backslashes escape the ", so the " are part of Variable content.

Comment: Then what is the difference between project-conf.h and "project-conf.h"

Comment: You didn't show how this variable is used later on. Obviously the Author needed the quotes to be part of the content, maybe he will use it in a define like #include PROJECT_CONF_H  where you need quotes.